# Create Windows compatible Self-extract-zip in Linux

Tags: windows, linux, zip, extract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a zip file compatible with windows under linux](https://superuser.com/questions/5155/how-to-create-a-zip-file-compatible-with-windows-under-linux)

Is that possible. What software will do that?

Comment: Just give the users a normal `.zip` along with a link to the 7zip or WinRAR website. Hell, Windows itself can unpack `.zip` archives since WinXP.

Comment: This is not duplicated with "How to create a zip file compatible with windows under linux". I'm asking for self-extract zip which isn't a simple zip file but an executable file

Comment: @xiamx Have you found a solution for this? I have a similar situation and I'm stuck.

Comment: @DanF.I have not, but my usecase of it has disapearred

Answer (score 1):

[UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) appears to do everything you specify.

If you need others, look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression#Portable_Executable).

Comment: UPX is an executable-compressor. It does not create self-extracting zips.